# How can i pass arguments and capture them on a console app, in runtime?

Tags: c#, xamarin

The question is: my app is running, but now i want to pass an argument, to run another tasks. Is it possible?

regards

Comment: Yeah it's possible. Write a simple REPL.

Comment: Thanks, I took an example, FluentSharp. Checking if it does work.

Comment: @EricHotinger, FluentSharp gone smootly. Thanks for idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a thread to listen for input from the console.

Either in your main method, or somewhere else during startup, use the following code:

```
//Start thread to listen for commands
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForConsoleCommand));
thread.Name = "ListenForConsoleCommands";
thread.Start();
```

Then your thread to listen:

```
private static void ListenForConsoleCommand()
{
    while (listenForUserInput)
    {
        string orig_cmd = Console.ReadLine();

        //Do stuff with orig_cmd
    }
}
```

Don't forget to properly exit your thread.  If you register for CTRL+C to close your app, the ReadLine method will return null, so that is one way to check.  I normally also include an "EXIT" or "CLOSE" command for the interactive console.

Comment: Thanks. Just changed to a async Task, but with the same idea.